# How to pass a Pointer member inside a class

Tags: pointers, sharepoint-2010, ros

I have a callback function (for ROS subscriber of type PointCloud2 msg).
I want to be able to pass a different pointer member inside the callback function because I saw that when I call the function twice there is a problem in the values of the variable that use this pointer.

This is part of my code:

```cpp
class Planner {
public:
  char frame_id[10] = "os1_lidar";
  int num_area = 1;
  
  int i = 0; // for create the circular path
  float right_point_y = 0;
  float left_point_y = 0;
  float y_distance = 0; //the distance between the trees in the Y axis
  float center_point_y = 0; //the center point between the trees in the y axis after average calculation
  float right_center_point_x = 0; //the center point of the right tree in the x axis
  float left_center_point_x = 0; //the center point of the left tree in the x axis
  float max_center_point_y = 1.4; //the max distance in the 7 axis for sending to arduino the steering angle
  
  //setting the two side area of the trees to filter the point cloud
  float minX_r = -5, minY_r = 2, minZ_r = -0.4;
  float maxX_r = -2, maxY_r = 4, maxZ_r = -0.1;
  float minX_l = -5, minY_l = -4, minZ_l = -0.4;
  float maxX_l = -2, maxY_l = -2, maxZ_l = 0.1;
  
  int red, green, blue = 0; //for change the boxes' color outside the lines
  
  bool publish_points = true;
  bool publish_markers = true;
  
  ros::Publisher point_cloud_pub;
  ros::Publisher center_point_marker_pub;
  ros::Publisher right_point_marker_pub;
  ros::Publisher left_point_marker_pub;
  ros::Publisher marker_area_right_pub;
  ros::Publisher marker_area_left_pub;
  
  
  void Point_Filtering(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud_msg);
}

void Planner::Point_Filtering(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud_msg) {
  ROS_INFO_STREAM_ONCE("Getting Data from Lidar");
  ROS_INFO_STREAM_ONCE("size " << cloud_msg->size());
  ROS_INFO_STREAM_ONCE("width " << cloud_msg->width);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM_ONCE("height " << cloud_msg->height);
  // Right Line
  
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered_r(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  //Left Line
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered_l(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  
  //Right Trees Box Filter
  pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter_r;
  boxFilter_r.setInputCloud(cloud_msg);
  boxFilter_r.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(minX_r, minY_r, minZ_r, 1.0));
  boxFilter_r.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(maxX_r, maxY_r, maxZ_r, 1.0));
  boxFilter_r.setNegative(false);
  boxFilter_r.setTranslation(Eigen::Vector3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
  boxFilter_r.filter(*cloud_filtered_r);
  
  //Left Trees Box Filter
  pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter_l;
  boxFilter_l.setInputCloud(cloud_msg);
  boxFilter_l.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(minX_l, minY_l, minZ_l, 1.0));
  boxFilter_l.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(maxX_l, maxY_l, maxZ_l, 1.0));
  boxFilter_l.setNegative(false);
  boxFilter_l.setTranslation(Eigen::Vector3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
  boxFilter_l.filter(*cloud_filtered_l);
  
  //Right Trees (Y axis)
  Eigen::Vector4f centroid_r_y;
  pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered_r, centroid_r_y);
  right_point_y = centroid_r_y[1];
  
  //Left Trees (Y axis)
  Eigen::Vector4f centroid_l_y;
  pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered_l, centroid_l_y);
  left_point_y = centroid_l_y[1];
  
  y_distance = abs(centroid_l_y[1]) + abs(centroid_r_y[1]);
  center_point_y = (abs(centroid_l_y[1]) - abs(centroid_r_y[1])) / 2;
  
  //Right Trees (X axis)
  Eigen::Vector4f centroid_r_x;
  pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered_r, centroid_r_x);
  right_center_point_x = centroid_r_x[0];
  //    ROS_INFO_STREAM("right_point_x : "<< num_area << " :" << right_center_point_x);
  
  
  //Left Trees (X axis)
  Eigen::Vector4f centroid_l_x;
  pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered_l, centroid_l_x);
  left_center_point_x = centroid_l_x[0];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ROS_INFO_STREAM_ONCE("Running");
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init(argc, argv, "pcl_filter_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  //region 1st
  Planner planner;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("/fused_points", 1, 
    &Planner::Point_Filtering, &planner);
  planner.num_area = 1;
  planner.minX_r = -3;
  planner.minX_l = -3;
  planner.maxX_r = 0;
  planner.maxX_l = 0;
  planner.point_cloud_pub = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("pcl_filtered", 1);
  planner.center_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("center_marker", 
    1);
  planner.right_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("right_marker", 
    1);
  planner.left_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("left_x_marker", 
    1);
  planner.marker_area_right_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("right_box_marker", 
    1);
  planner.marker_area_left_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("left_box_marker", 
    1);
  //endregion
  
  //region 2nd
  Planner planner_2;
  planner_2.num_area = 2;
  planner_2.minX_r = -8 ;
  planner_2.minX_l = -8;
  planner_2.maxX_r = -5;
  planner_2.maxX_l = -5;
  planner_2.publish_points = false;
  planner_2.point_cloud_pub = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("pcl_filtered_2", 
    1);
  planner_2.center_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> 
    ("center_marker_2", 1);
  planner_2.right_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> 
    ("right_marker_2", 1);
  planner_2.left_point_marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> 
    ("left_x_marker_2", 1);
  planner_2.marker_area_right_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> 
    ("right_box_marker_2", 1);
  planner_2.marker_area_left_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> 
    ("left_box_marker_2", 1);
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >("/fused_points", 1, 
    &Planner::Point_Filtering, &planner_2);
    
  //endregion
  ros::Rate r(15);
  ros::Time test_time;
  while (nh.ok()) {
    ros::spinOnce();
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

This code takes the original point clouds, filters it to relevant areas and then calculate centroid in those filtered point clouds.

I want to take this line :

> pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::Ptr cloud_filtered_r(new
> pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ);

and to put it in the public part of the class so I will be able to change this name of the filtered points.
When I subscribe to the same msg twice the centroid of the second area is equal to the first and this is wrong for me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code was missing closing curly brackets in two places. I think I've fixed that in the edit, but please check.

Comment: Please try  to provide a minimal example. This is absolutely too much code here.